# Error: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter

**Error:** RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

How to solve this error in this program, flutter.
I provide my code.

**Code:**

**home_screen.dart:**

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final nameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              emailTextField(),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              nameTextField(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emailTextField() {
    return CustomTextField(
        name: "Email", borderRadius: 20, controller: emailController);
  }

  Widget nameTextField() {
    return CustomTextField(
        name: "Name", borderRadius: 20, controller: nameController);
  }
}
```

This is Second file.
**customtextfield.dart:**

```
    class CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
      final String name;
      double borderRadius;
      final TextEditingController controller;
      CustomTextField(
          {super.key,
          required this.name,
          required this.borderRadius,
          required this.controller});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: TextFormField(
            controller: controller,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: name,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(borderRadius))),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Please! give me this problem answer,
in comment section.

Comment: try removing `Scaffold` from `CustomTextField`